# android textfield programatically based on data

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am Having a trouble. In  my project i am having a spinner . Each value i will select in spinner it will make an api call which in return is receiving various objects array.

Important : Each value in spinner will get data from api consisting of different array length.

What i want is to display that each value of array in a spinner .The thing is i am not finding any way to create only that amount of spinner which are equal to data in array.

Example :Spinner value is 1 and array we get from api call has 3 values. Then if spinner value is 2, array we get has 5 values. I have to create 3 spinners if spinner value is 1 and 5 spinners on layout if spinner value is 2 automatically.

Note : Array values can go upto 15 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for dynamic content. When you get different array from api change you `Adapter` data source and notify for `Adapter` for data change .

Check the link i provided,  there is a Adapter class called `MyAdapter`. You just have to update `mDataset` String Array and need to call [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). `Adapter` will automatically update its resource.

Comment: Can i create multiple spinners in recycler view based on data?

Comment: If you need multiple spinner you can create it. What i have mentioned here is If you select a option from spinner then you can create any amount to view dynamically with the help of RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just create one textview and use StringBuilder.append to append all values from the array with proper styling (meaning commas etc)

Comment: each value need to come on separate textview as they will be used for other purpose in return.

Comment: In that case you need to add array of textviews dynamically.

Comment: Yes but what will be mthod